# Layout for 3 uiImageView side by side using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, ios8

I want to create a control for ios 8+ where we have 3 images. In center image in big and left/right images are small.

I have to create some code in swift, using Stack Layout but it will not work in iOS 8 as it is available from ios 9. So need to change this. What should i use to keep images together (left and right bottom)?

Also another problem i have is, i need pan gesture on only big center image not on the small left and right image. So when i touch the big image i can move all three around the screen. Currently it if i touch any of 3 all moves.

**Functions**:

- small left/right image: Act as button for running a swift function
- middle image: on pan gesture drag all three around screen

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 choices to create an image slider according to your requirement.

1. Using Scroll view (`UIScrollView`)
2. Using Collection view (`UICollectionView`)
3. Using Page Controller

Here are simple/basic logic, how and what you should use to achieve sliding image.

**Using Scroll view (`UIScrollView`)**

1. Add three images in scroll view with equal width
2. Set Height of middle image, according to your requirement (bigger than other)
3. Set width of any one image (probably middle) equal or around equivalent percentage (80% equal) to device screen using AutoLayout constraint.
4. Scroll view automatically scroll horizontally according to horizontal content size. You don't need to add Pan gesture.
5. You can also enable paging of scroll view.

**Using Collection view (`UICollectionView`)**

1. Add collection view with three (static) cells or single dynamic (You need to choose how do you want to update this feature in future. If you choose single dynamic cell then you can easily add more images in slider by adding its data into datasource variable, in future.)
2. Enable horizontal scroll only in collection view.
3. Update (make it bigger) Image height in data source method using index path for item (indexPath.item == 1).
4. Collection view have pan gesture also. You don't need to implement it.
5. You can enable pagination also.
6. Note: Set image/cell width equal to device screen or equivalent.

**Using Page Controller**
Here are nice reference tutorials, "How to use Page View Controller"

- [How To Create UIPageViewController Using Storyboard](https://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/)
- [How to Use UIPageViewController to Build Tutorial Screens](https://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/)

I do not recommend this option (Page view controller) but you have provided complete details about scope of your requirement (view controller level or it is simple child view slider), so this is an option to image slider also.

Comment: i have used another way of doing this. I will use your approach for some other task. For now as i just needed 3 images side by side i programmatically added them. As done in post shown below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46524174/programmatically-place-partial-image-over-another-in-uiview-using-swift-3