# Programmatically place partial image over another in UIView using Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, uiview, ios8

I just started working on Swift last week and i need a suggestion if the following approach is right ways of laying partial image on top of another image.

I have a UIView in which I am creating 3 images programmatically. Left arrow image, middle mobile image and right arrow image as shown below. Can I partially place arrow images 50% on the mobile image?

I have tried:

```
func setupUI(){
    let mobileImage = UIImage(named: "mobile")
    let arrowImage = UIImage(named: "arrow")

    middleView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: arrowImage!.size.width/2, y:0 , width:mobileImage!.size.width, height:mobileImage!.size.height))
    middleView.image = mobileImage
    middleView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    middleView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    self.addSubview(middleView)

    let yForArrow =  mobileImage!.size.height - arrowImage!.size.height
    leftArrow = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:yForArrow, width:arrowImage!.size.width, height:arrowImage!.size.height))
    leftArrow.image = arrowImage
    self.addSubview(leftArrow)

    let rightArrowX = mobileImage!.size.width
    rightView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: rightArrowX, y:yForArrow, width:arrowImage!.size.width, height:arrowImage!.size.height))
    rightView.image = arrowImage
    self.addSubview(rightView)
}
```

*At start it was not working, as i forgot to add setupUI() in init method. As shown in answer bellow.

Is setting frame correct way of doing it OR i should be using constraints?

To me it looks bad approach as i am hard coding the numbers in CGRect.

[image]

*This image is created in MS paint to show what it should look on iPhone.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: If the problem is that the image is being cut off then you probably should set the clipToBounds of the image to false

Comment: i will post full code here. But why has question been given -4 points. I have some problem in code that is why it is not working. This image is created in MS paint to show what it should look on iPhone.

Comment: I think that some users are downvoting because it is still not clear what the problem is. Your frames seem to be correct (st least for the x, nut sure about the y), but I don't understand what you don't like. Are the images being cut? Are they misaligned? Could you show the final result with details about the issue?

Comment: i missed adding setupUI() in init method so images were not getting rendered. Also in question i wanted to ask if setting frame is correct way of doing it or i should be using constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem i missed adding setupUI() in init method.

SetupUI programatically adds images on UIView. As it was missing so no image was appearing in the iPhone simulator.

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupUI() // Code to add images in UIView
    }
```